# Tag "metadata" onto an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code which assembles two-dimensional arrays to be sent to the Spreadsheet gem's excel-building methods.  I'd like to "tag" some subarrays (corresponding to rows) with formatting codes like `{:color => "red"}`.

Can anyone see a way of doing this?  I could achieve a similar result by storing a seperate object which has the formatting option and (for example) the indexes to all rows i want to apply that format to.  But it would be nicer if I could stick it straight onto the row itself as i build my data.

One thing that occurred to me is to use some kind of namespaced hash as the last entry in an array, if i want to format it, and then strip that out again in the spreadsheet builder.  But, this seems risky as it's then in the array's actual data.  Is there any kind of instance variable or something i can tap into with an array to "shove" my metadata in there?

I'm using Rails 2.2 for this app, in case that's relevant.

Comment: All OPs hate this question but why on Earth do you still use Rails 2.2?

Comment: It's not my preference: we're kind of stuck with it at the moment.  I would dearly love to upgrade, believe me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each row contains data and possibly some metadata, it seems natural to represent all rows as an Array of Hashes, where each Hash contains a `:data` key and a `:metadata` key. The latter can be omitted  or can just point to an empty Hash if you do not have any metadata for the row, whichever you prefer.

I have no experience with the Spreadsheet gem, but I assume it requires an Array of Arrays as input, which you can create in a straightforward manner from the Array of Hashes as shown in the code below.

```
rows = [
  {
    data: [2, 3, 5],

    metadata: { color: 'red' }
  },
  {
    data: [7, 11, 13],

    metadata: {}
  }
]

# Transform into Array of Arrays, removing all metadata
rows.map { |row| row[:data] }
# => [[2, 3, 5], [7, 11, 13]]
```

Comment: I think you're right:  it's best to build it as an explicitly different structure like this.  I can make my importing code look to see if each row is an array or hash, and if it's a hash use the data part as the data and the metadata for the formatting.   Thanks for the common sense sanity check :)